# Regex replace quotation marks in markdown

Tags: markdown

I'm a writer and have dialogue within double quotes (US standard). For example:

"This is a line of dialogue, 'with a nested quote' which find & replace won't pickup with much accuracy."

However different publishers (and countries) have different standards. UK for example is:

'This is a line of dialogue, "with a nested quote" which find & replace won't pickup with much accuracy.'

Breaking down the logic, the rules would be along the following lines to go FROM what I've got (US standard), to UK standard.

```
Start
  REPEAT
    Replace " with ' AND ' with " #the tricky part
  IGNORE                          #another tricky part
    n't
    t's
    y've
    y're
  UNTIL done
END without screwing it up because it'd be a nightmare to play whack a quotation-mark in a 100,000 word manuscript
```

The tricky part from my POV is the order of replacement

Some ideas:

- The abbreviations in the IGNORE list could be substituted for another character in the short term then restore once the double quotes are replaced with single? But this would need to be performed ONLY if the abbreviation is within quotes, not a blanket replace through the files.
- Perhaps the difference could be made clearer between the different marks by searching on ASCII values instead?